# JavaScript performance - global variables

Tags: javascript

In my project I'm using JavaScript language file which is an object and all language keys are this object properties e.g. `o_language['name'] = 'Name'` next I have single .js files where each of them is a single object containing all functions for single PHP view e.g.

```
o_add_card = {
   init: function(){...},
   do_something: function(){..},
   do_something_2: function(){..}
}
```

In loader.js I'm loading all necessary objects, and then I know that I can call language in few different ways but I don't understand which is fastest and why.

1st method - I can use global o_language straight e.g.

```
o_add_card = {
   init: function(){...},
   do_something: function(){
       alert(o_language['name']);
   },
}
```

2nd method - I can use global o_language assigned to object property e.g.

```
o_add_card = {
   lang: o_language['name'],
   init: function(){...},
   do_something: function(){
       alert(this.lang['name']);
   },
}
```

3rd method - I can use global o_language assigned to object property and create function var e.g.

```
o_add_card = {
   lang: o_language['name'],
   init: function(){...},
   do_something: function(){
       var o_lang = this.lang;
       alert(o_lang ['name']);
   },
}
```

4th method - I can use global o_language assigned to function variable e.g.

```
o_add_card = {
   init: function(){...},
   do_something: function(){
       var o_lang = o_language['name'];
       alert(o_lang ['name']);
   },
}
```

EDIT: maybe I try to explain it better. Theoretical situation:

```
<script>
    global_o_language = {
        name: 'name',
        //... (approx 500 other properties)
    }
    global_o_add_card: {
        lang: global_o_language,
        init: function(){
            this.function_1();
            // ... other functions coming here
        },
        function_1: function(){
            var o_lang = this.lang;

            // I don't care about using dot or brackets here, but about using global or local var's
            // I can use global variable straight
            alert(global_o_language['name'] );

            // I can load global variable to object property and use it like that
            alert(this.lang['name'] );

            //or create local variable inside function where I assign global one or `this` property
            alert(o_lang['name'] );
        }
    }
    global_o_add_card.init();
</script>
```

I just want to know which practice is better and do I should care about it.

Comment: I'm not sure what your asking, but when you set a property: `lang: o_language['name']` then use this property, this is wrong `this.lang['name']`, this is correct `this.lang`. You are assigning the property lang from the `o_language['name']` property, unless that property returns an object the way you use it is wrong. Otherwise ignore me

Comment: There isn't a fastest way... but direct property calls I guess would be. `this.object.property` over `this.object['property']`

Comment: Are you really doing this millions of times? If not, it's not going to much matter - stop prematurely optimizing. For example, a property access performance test here got 1,154,538,876 accesses per second. [Dot is significantly faster on some browsers, `['']` is slightly faster on others](http://jsperf.com/testaccessobjectnotation/2).

Comment: I did edit my post, maybe It will better explain what I have meant.

Comment: the second and third methods will result in issues if the original value changes during the life of the page. That leaves the first and the fourth, which are near identical. I'm sure there are other places where you could improve performance more significantly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others mentioned here, there is no fastest way to access object properties (. vs ['']) in JavaScript because this is largely platform-dependent.

Also notice that your 4 methods are hardly comparable, because methods 2, 3 and 4 are only more complex versions of the first method, so if you want to know which is the fastest one (at least theoretically), then the answer is: the first one.

```
// 1 operation
o_add_card = {
   init: function(){...},
   do_something: function(){
       alert(o_language['name']); // 1 operation - read property from global object
   },
}

// 3 operations + 1 extra object property
o_add_card = {
   lang: o_language['name'], // 2 operations - read property from global object 
                             //              - assign it to local property
                             // + 1 extra property to store for the current object
   init: function(){...},
   do_something: function(){
       alert(this.lang['name']); // 1 operation - read property from local object
   },
}

// 5 operations + 1 extra property + 1 extra variable
o_add_card = {
   lang: o_language['name'], // 2 operations - read property from global object 
                             //              - assign it to local property
                             // 1 more property to store for the current object
   init: function(){...},
   do_something: function(){
       var o_lang = this.lang; // 2 operations - same as above + the extra variable
       alert(o_lang ['name']); // 1 operation - read property from global object
   },
}

// 3 operations + 1 extra variable
o_add_card = {
   init: function(){...},
   do_something: function(){
       var o_lang = o_language['name']; // 2 operations - same as above + the extra variable
       alert(o_lang ['name']); // 1 operation - read property from global object
   },
}
```

As Dark Falcon said, you won't see any performance differences between those 4 methods unless you call your method millions of times. And even then, the difference will be unnoticeable.

Because of this matter, the only thing you should consider when making a decision is code quality.

If you need that extra property or that extra variable for your code to be more easy to understand and to maintain, for you or for others, then do it.

Also keep in mind that there are countless situations in which declaring an extra variable or executing 3 operations instead of 1 improves code readability, and sometimes even performance, so don't be afraid to do it when you think it's gonna help.

For your example in particular, I'd go with the first method if `o_language['name']` is accessed only once or twice inside `do_something`, but I'd go with the fourth method if `o_language['name']` is accessed multiple times inside `do_something`, because for me it's easier to read, and if you ever need to rename `o_language['name']`, then you only have to modify in a single place (`var o_lang = o_language['name']`) instead of 3 or more, so it's easier to maintain (assuming you don't want to use Find & Replace or some advanced refactoring tool).

Also, if you feel comfortable with assigning some global object property to a local object property, then do it. I do it for example when I have a global `Configuration` object, which has different properties for different modules / components, and then each module / component object could have it's own Configuration property, taken from the global object.

But still, it's more of a matter of taste than a recommendation.